# How to use Git Ignore on a self-emptying folder

Tags: git, ignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I've got a git repo setup something like

```
Main
   -> Build
   -> Assets
   -> Resources
```

However, every time I compile our application, the "Build" directory gets completely wiped, thus deleting any .gitignore files within it.

How can I set a ignore to ignore that directory, from outside of it? something like:

Main/.gitignore

```
ignore /Build/*
ignore /Build
```

Many thanks

Update:

Our /Main/.gitignore looks like

```
### OSX ###
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes


### Build ###
# Build folder and log file
Build/
Build/**/*
build.log
build
npm-debug.log
tmp
.map
```

However SourceTree on OSX is still showing them as available to commit.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to create the `.gitignore` file into your `Main` directory and write inside that file the entries of the directories you want to exclude.
For example, type in your terminal `cd Main && echo "Build/" >> .gitignore` (if you are using Linux).
Read this for other information: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files